# How to access nested object value using string so I can edit?

Tags: javascript

**If I have the following string or array:**

```
var thestring = '[0]["more"][0]["more"][0]["text"]';
var thearray = ['0','more','0','more','0','text'];
```

**How can I use that string or array to identify a part of an object so I can edit it?**

```
var theobject = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "text":"hello",
        "more": [
            {
                "id":2,
                "text":"hello",
                "more":[
                    {
                        "id":3,
                        "text":"hello", // I want to edit this
                        "more": [
                            {
                                "id":4,
                                "text":"hello",
                                "more":[
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
         ]
    },
    {
        "id":5,
        "text":"hello"
    },
    {
        "id":6,
        "text":"hello"
    },
    {
        "id":7,
        "text":"hello"
    }
];
```

**Basically I am trying to access this part of the object:**

```
theobject[0]["more"][0]["more"][0]["text"];
```

**But if I do it with a string it doesn't work:**

```
theobject[thestring];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it without dependencies, this function will update the value described by `thearray`:

```
function setObjectValue(o, a, v) {
    a = a.slice(); // copy array
    p = a.pop(); // get last value for updating
    a.forEach(function(p) { o = o[p]; }); // traverse object for each property in a
    o[p] = v; // update the final value
}
```

Usage: `setObjectValue(theobject, thearray, 'UPDATED')`

Comment: Nice!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Is it possible to do this with a for() loop instead of forEach? (just for better compatibility).

Comment: Sure, just replace the forEach line with `for (x=0; x<a.length; x++) { o = o[a[x]]; }`

Comment: Nice answer, I like the approach!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at lodash _.get and _.set functions, they allow you to access an object using a path type syntax, e.g.

```
_.get(object, 'property1.property2.property3', defaultValue);
```

An equivalent _.set function exists, they are both useful.

https://lodash.com/docs#get

https://lodash.com/docs#set

From the lodash docs:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
```

The ability to provide a default object is nice too, it makes accessing a deeply nexted object quite easy.

Set works in a similar way:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.set(object, 'a[0].b.c', 4);
console.log(object.a[0].b.c);
// => 4

_.set(object, ['x', '0', 'y', 'z'], 5);
console.log(object.x[0].y.z);
// => 5
```